# How to assign ForeignKey MySQL item in views.py?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

When I save my NoteForm, I want to save my form and the "note" field, then I want to create a "tag" for the Note in the NoteTagModel.

At the moment, I create a new tag but it is not assigned to the note. I know that the following code must be wrong:

```
notetag.id = new_note_parse.id
```

If I change to:

```
notetag.note = new_note_parse.id
```

I receive the following error:

```
"NoteTagModel.note" must be a "NoteModel" instance.
```

The below is my **views.py**:

```
def notes(request):

    note_form = NoteForm
    notetag = NoteTagModel()

    note_form=NoteForm(request.POST)
    if note_form.is_valid():
        new_note = note_form.save(commit=False)
        new_note_parse = new_note
        new_note.save()

        notetag.id = new_note_parse.id
        notetag.tag = "Test"

        notetag.save()
    
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notes:notes'))

    context = {
        'note_form' : note_form,
        'notes' : NoteModel.objects.all(),
        'notes_tag' : NoteTagModel.objects.all(),
        
    }

    return render(request, "notes/notes.html", context)
```

My **models.py** is:

```
class NoteModel(models.Model):
    note = models.CharField(
        max_length = 5000
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.note}"

class NoteTagModel(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(
        NoteModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="notes",
        blank= False,
        null = True,
    )

    tag = models.CharField(
        max_length = 5000
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Note: {self.note} | Tag: {self.tag}"
```

I have the following as my **forms.py**:

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NoteModel
        fields = [
            'note',
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change views.py to reflect the below:

```
note = NoteModel.objects.get(id=new_note_parse.id)

        notetag.note = note
```